# Grouping rectangles in iTextSharp

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, rectangles

I have multiple rectangles and they all share the same spot color. Is there a way to merge / group them into one vector object so the generated pdf has smaller size?

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating the document from scratch, then the answer is trivial: yes!

It's sufficient to draw all the paths of the rectangles that share the same spot color and then use the operator that fills, stroke or fills & strokes the paths.

If you are talking about optimizing an existing PDF document, you're in for some heavy programming. You would need to parse every content stream looking for rectangle operators (assuming that the rectangles aren't drawn using move-to and line-to operators), check where these shapes are filled and/or stroked, and then rearrange all these operators. This would require a lot of thought. I would know where to begin, but I can't predict where it would end. Maybe it would turn out that it makes more sense to define a single rectangle as a Form XObject and reuse that single external object, maybe not. It's hard to predict.

Moreover: you are talking about operators in a stream. These streams are compressed anyway, so you may be doing a lot of work to gain only a very small decrease in size.

I would say: what you are asking for may be possible, but it is unclear why you would do this, because it would result in only a limited decrease in file size.

If size is an issue, there may be other places where you are "wasting bytes" that could result in a more desirable result. I am very curious to hear why you think the rectangles using spot colors are the culprit. You are *reusing* the spot color instance, aren't you? If you are creating a new spot color instance for every rectangle you draw, you have found the real culprit and you can avoid having to group the rectangles.